# Want to assign foreign key from views.py file

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I created a post model that is linked to the user by the foreign key(author). I don't want the user to set the foreign key of the post. I want the active user(who wrote the post) to be the foreign key of the post.

```
Models.py file-
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    message = models.TextField()
    message_html = models.TextField(editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.message_html = misaka.html(self.message)
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:single',kwargs={'username':self.user.username,'pk':self.pk})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        unique_together = ['auther','message']
```

The form class of this model-

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        fields=("heading","message")
        model=Post

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["heading"].label = "Heading"
        self.fields["message"].label = "Write Blog"
```

The view function that is creating the model post. In this function, I want to set the active user as foreign key.

```
@login_required
def CreatePost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_form = PostForm(data=request.POST)
        if post_form.is_valid():
            post = post_form.save()
            post.author=request.user.username
            post.save()
            return redirect('/my_profile')
        else:
            print(post_form.errors)
    else:
        post_form=PostForm()
    return render(request,'create_post.html',{'post_form':post_form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this does nto work is because `post_form.save()` will already try to save the `Post` object to the database. You can however simply alter the instance wrapped in the form.

Furthermore since the `author` is a `ForeignKey` to a `User` object, you should pass `request.user`, not `request.user.username`:

```
@login_required
def CreatePost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_form = PostForm(data=request.POST)
        if post_form.is_valid():
            post_form.instance.author = request.user
            post = post_form.save()
            return redirect('/my_profile')
        else:
            print(post_form.errors)
    else:
        post_form=PostForm()
    return render(request,'create_post.html',{'post_form':post_form})
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).